# How to find special characters (say like the musical symbol which denotes when a song is being played

Tags: debian, editors, special-characters

Sometimes I edit subtitle files (.srt) and at times I get a place where the music symbol should be used. I am nonplussed as to how to get the music symbol to come up in the editor. I use editors such as subitlteditor and featherpad and can use either to do the editing but failing to figure out how to get the music symbol notation. I am on Debian testing/bullseye if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the simplest approach (when I don’t have a keyboard shortcut for the symbol I’m after) is to use GNOME’s Character Map:

[image: Screenshot of the Character Map, showing U+2269 selected]

Find the symbol you want, either by looking for it in the appropriate block, or by searching for it by name; in this case I did the latter, searching for “note”. Then you can copy it to the clipboard, either directly by selecting it and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, or through the “Text to copy” field by double-clicking on the symbol and clicking on the “Copy” button. Finally, paste it into your editor; subtitleeditor at least supports UTF-8 fine so there’s no issue there.

(Whether the tool used to *view* subtitles supports the symbols you add is another matter; SRT used CP-1252 at first, but UTF-8 support is now widespread, [and officially documented](https://www.matroska.org/technical/specs/subtitles/srt.html).)